# Is there a faster way to get a random record from a MySQL table through ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails application, I'm using this to get a random row from a MySQL table:

```
contact = Contact.find(:all, :limit => 1, :order => 'RAND()')[0]
```

Even though the table only has about 20,000 rows it takes a couple seconds. Does anyone know of a faster way?

---

Update

Also tried just running the SQL in the console...

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

It still takes a long time, like two or three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Get one rand from ruby and then transform it to your primary key